# Adding several labels (year/month) to a graph in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

I would like to add several labels to a plot in `pgfplots`: one label for the month and one for the year, just like in this graph:

[image]

I tried to use the `extra tick label`, but I don't know how it is possible to change its format from month to year, so the extra and normal x label have the same format. Also I could not figure out how to get the ticks shifted so that they are left and right of the month label instead of centered.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
xtick=data,
extra x ticks={2009-10-01, 2010-02-01},
extra x tick style={yshift=-20pt},
%extra xticklabel=\year, % does not work
xticklabel style={anchor=near xticklabel},
xticklabel=\month,
date ZERO=2009-08-01,% <- improves precision!
]
\addplot coordinates {
(2009-08-01, 050)
(2009-09-01, 100)
(2009-10-01, 100)
(2009-11-01, 100)
(2009-12-01, 040)
(2010-01-01, 020)
(2010-02-01, 000)
(2010-03-01, 035)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### EDIT

In order to get vertical lines between the different months labels, I tried to use Jakes approach and tried to name the nodes `\year\month`, e.g. 20102 (2010 Feb). The problem with that is that the months `(\month)` contain leading zeros and the parser parses them as octal numbers. So when I try to calculate `\month-1` to get the node before the current one, I receive a parser error. In order to solve that I tried to use the methods provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20445/abbreviated-month-names-as-tick-labels-in-pgfplots), but none of them worked so far.

### MWE2

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\monthnames{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
xtick=data,
xticklabel style={
    anchor=near xticklabel,     
        % Approach 1: Does not work missing endcsname error
    %name=\ifnodedefined{start\year{\pgfcalendar{tickcal}{\tick}{\tick}{\pgfcalendarshorthand{m}{-}}}} 
        %{end\year}  % Then this could be the last month
        %{start\year}, % Otherwise, start the year      
        % Approach 2: Does not work missing endcsname error
    %name=\ifnodedefined{start\year\pgfmathparse{\monthnames[Mod(\tick-1,12)]}\pgfmathresult} % Does not work missing endcsname error
        %{end\year}  % Then this could be the last month
        %{start\year}, % Otherwise, start the year      
},
xticklabel=\month,
date ZERO=2009-08-01,% <- improves precision!
]
\addplot coordinates {
(2009-08-01, 050)
(2009-09-01, 100)
(2009-10-01, 100)
(2009-11-01, 100)
(2009-12-01, 040)
(2010-01-01, 020)
(2010-02-01, 000)
(2010-03-01, 035)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For changing the format just put other specification into the `extra x tick style` option. In your case write `extra x tick style={yshift=-20pt,xticklabel=\year}`

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100779/draw-group-line-error/100813#100813

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You almost had it: The extra tick labels can accept all the same options as the normal tick labels, you just need to provide them via `extra x tick style={<normal tick options>}`. In this case, you would say `extra x tick style={xticklabel=\year}`.

If you want to fancy things up a little bit, you can draw the group lines automatically, using a bit of trickery with naming the label nodes and checking for the existence of named nodes using the approach from [Checking whether or not a node has been previously defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85528/checking-whether-or-not-a-node-has-been-previously-defined):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 

\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
xtick=data,
extra x ticks={2009-10-01, 2010-02-01},
extra x tick style={
    yshift=-3.5ex,
    xticklabel=\year,
    xticklabel style={name={}},
    major tick length=0pt
},
xticklabel style={
    anchor=near xticklabel,
    name=\ifnodedefined{start\year} % Have we already started this year?
        {end\year}  % Then this could be the last month
        {start\year}, % Otherwise, start the year
    append after command=
        \pgfextra{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\lastyear{\year-1}}
        \ifnodedefined{end\lastyear}
        {
                {\ifnum\month=1 (start\lastyear.south west) edge (end\lastyear.south east) \pgfextra{\xdef\finalyear{\year}}\fi}}
        {}
},
after end axis/.code={
    \draw (start\finalyear.south west) -- (end\finalyear.south east);
},
xticklabel=\month,
date ZERO=2009-08-01,% <- improves precision!
]
\addplot coordinates {
(2009-08-01, 050)
(2009-09-01, 100)
(2009-10-01, 100)
(2009-11-01, 100)
(2009-12-01, 040)
(2010-01-01, 020)
(2010-02-01, 000)
(2010-03-01, 035)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Or, similarly, if you want vertical separating lines between the years:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
xtick=data,
tick pos=left,
yticklabel style={append after command={(\tikzlastnode.east) edge +(0.15cm,0)}},
major tick length=0pt,
extra x ticks={2009-10-01, 2010-02-01},
extra x tick style={
    yshift=-3.5ex,
    xticklabel=\year,
    xticklabel style={name={}},
    every x tick label/.style={}
},
xticklabel style={
    anchor=near xticklabel,
    alias=tick\ticknum,
    name=\ifnodedefined{start\year} % Have we already started this year?
        {end\year}  % Then this could be the last month
        {start\year}, % Otherwise, start the year
    append after command=
        \pgfextra{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\lastyear{\year-1}}
        \ifnodedefined{end\lastyear}
        {
                {\ifnum\month=1 ({$(end\lastyear.south west)!0.5!(start\year.south east)$}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) edge ++(0,-7ex)
                \fi}
        }
        {}
        \ifnum\ticknum>0
                \ifnum\month>1
                    \pgfextra{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\prevticknum{\ticknum-1}}
        ($(tick\prevticknum.north east)!0.5!(tick\ticknum.north west)$) edge ++({0,-3ex})
                \fi
        \fi
},
after end axis/.code={
    \draw (rel axis cs:0,0) -- ++(0,-7ex)
            (rel axis cs:1,0) -- ++(0,-7ex);
},
xticklabel=\month,
date ZERO=2009-08-01,% <- improves precision!
]
\addplot coordinates {
(2009-08-01, 050)
(2009-09-01, 100)
(2009-10-01, 100)
(2009-11-01, 100)
(2009-12-01, 040)
(2010-01-01, 020)
(2010-02-01, 000)
(2010-03-01, 035)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. You seem to know everything about pgfplots! I think it might look better, if the lines are vertical like in the example graph. I wanted to take a look into that later.

Comment: @maetra: I've edited my answer to show how you can get vertical separating lines.

Comment: great work, imho vertical lines for the month labels would make look even better

Comment: I tried to get the vertical lines for the months too, but with `\pgfextra{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\lastmonth{\month-1}}` I get a pgfmatherror since the month labels are written as '08' instead of '8'. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: @maetra: You could use `\numexpr` to do the calculations instead of `\pgfmathparse`, or you could use the `\ticknum` macro instead, which contains the current tick number. I've used the second method in my edited answer.

Comment: thanks again, I didn't know about `ticknum`, that is clearly the better approach. By the way, have you already finished your article on tufte-scatter-plots? It would love to use that style with tikz.

Comment: Trying the second variant, I get `Package pgf Error: No shape named tick9 is known.`I have put my `xticks` to the 15th of each month, so that the month labels are actually below the month (and not the start of the month).

Comment: I put in this code to add the ticks, works fine now: `\ifdefined\prevticknum ($(tick\prevticknum.north east)!0.5!(tick\ticknum.north west)$) edge ++({0,-3ex}) \fi\pgfextra{\global\let\prevticknum\ticknum}`