# pgfplots Axis-Subsections on X-Axis on a bargraph?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to get pgfplots to draw some bargraph like this:

[image]

but I cannot figure out how to get `pgfplots` to add the second X-axis-labeling so I could actually draw the data in a way that would be easily readable. I checked out the manual but could not quite find anything about it. I've been trying to figure this out quite a while now but I cannot get it to work.

Can somebody give me a minimal example on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Take a look at [Two Level Labels in Bar Plot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71350/two-level-labels-in-bar-plot). Would that approach work for you?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX. Can you give us the part that draws the plot without the second axis to avoid replicating the actual plot?

Comment: Thanks Jake, that approach seems pretty nice and helps a lot. Seems like it includes some additional content for pgfplots?

percusse, I do not have a working sample that draws without the second axis yet since I did not figure how I can add the same content to an axis multiple times. (i.e. I have a measurement at setting a x and at b x, yet I did not see how to get that to work since \xticklabels merges same entries into one.

Comment: @locutus We only need a plot that draws the bars such that we don't start from scratch writing `\documentclass{...` just to try out some ideas about a possible answer. That's usually called MWE(minimum workable example). Well the original MWE stands for working example but it doesn't have to be working to work on.

Answer (score 2):

So here is the solution I managed to put up. I used the example from Jakes link and it solved the problem pretty much the way it should. Also, with using the table, I was able to use the same axis-label several times, so all is fine.

[image: Diagram with 2 x-axis labels]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcounter{groupcount}
\pgfplotsset{
    draw group line/.style n args={5}{
        after end axis/.append code={
            \setcounter{groupcount}{0}
            \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#1}\of\datatable\as\cell{%
                \def\temp{#2}
                \ifx\temp\cell
                    \ifnum\thegroupcount=0
                        \stepcounter{groupcount}
                        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{[index]0}\of\datatable
                        \coordinate [yshift=#4] (startgroup) at (axis cs:\pgfplotsretval,0);
                    \else
                        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{[index]0}\of\datatable
                        \coordinate [yshift=#4] (endgroup) at (axis cs:\pgfplotsretval,0);
                    \fi
                \else
                    \ifnum\thegroupcount=1
                        \setcounter{groupcount}{0}
                        \draw [
                            shorten >=-#5,
                            shorten <=-#5
                        ] (startgroup) -- node [anchor=north] {#3} (endgroup);
                    \fi
                \fi
            }
            \ifnum\thegroupcount=1
                        \setcounter{groupcount}{0}
                        \draw [
                            shorten >=-#5,
                            shorten <=-#5
                        ] (startgroup) -- node [anchor=north] {#3} (endgroup);
            \fi
        }
    }
}


\pgfplotstableread{
1  15 4 1
2  13 3 1
3  18 5 2
4  10 1 2
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=label,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels={x, y, x, y},
    enlarge y limits=false,
    enlarge x limits=0.1,
    ymin=0,ymax=25,
    ybar,
    bar width=20pt,
    legend style={
      font=\footnotesize,
      cells={anchor=west},
      legend columns=5,
      at={(0.5,-0.2)},
      anchor=north,
      /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.2cm}
    },
    draw group line={[index]3}{1}{a}{-3.5ex}{7pt},
    draw group line={[index]3}{2}{b}{-3.5ex}{7pt},
]

\addplot+[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit] table[x index=0,y index=1,y error index=2] \datatable;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I noticed a minor flaw with this one though: If you have a group that has only one bar, it throws an error. The solution is pretty simple to just add the content of the first else to the first ifnum.