# How to make a tidy grouped and stacked barchart?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, charts

I found this chart in a recent paper. I've emailed the author about it but they didn't reply.

I want to create something similar but I don't know what the correct software to use is.

I need the following:

- category grouping (small/medium/large)
- column/bar labelling (1, 2, 4)
- stacked bars (comp/mem/TLB/idle) <-- maybe stacked isn't the right word, but I also need to show a percentage breakdown in the same way.
- grayscale. This image is very printer-friendly

Can this be done with pgfplots? If not, what software could I use?

[image: barchart]

Comment: Have a look at package `pgfplots` and its `y bar stacked`-feature.

Comment: there must be a duplicate for that but yo ucan start from this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55554/how-can-i-mix-an-ybar-and-an-ybar-stacked-with-pgfplots

Comment: Furthermore to the approach linked by @percusse, you could hatch certain parts, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54464/hatch-a-rectangle-in-tikz, to adress your printer friendlyness/black and white request.

Comment: This looks very similar to [Two level labels in bar plot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71350/two-level-labels-in-bar-plot)

Comment: @user2965755, did any of the tricks in the comment help you to solve the problem?