# How to interrupt a plot?

Tags: pgfplots

Please consider the following example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
1   19.178  26.027  8.219   6.849   39.726  1
2   54.795  21.918  4.110   6.849   12.329  1
3   28.767  16.438  6.849   8.219   39.726  1
4   63.014  2.740   2.740   8.219   28.767  2
5   90.411  1.370   6.849   0.000   1.370  2
6   15.068  2.740   16.438  8.219   57.534  2
7   67.123  0.000   0.000   1.000   32.877  3
8   72.603  6.849   5.479   5.000   15.068  3
9   56.164  12.329  6.849   4.110   20.548  3
10  50.685  4.110   8.219   1.370   35.616  3
}\datatable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=4] \datatable;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

What I want to do is to interrupt the plot, *without modifying the table* (if possible), at desired locations to get something like this (I obtained the image by manually erasing some connecting lines):

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to do this with just one `\addplot`, but if that's not possible, any alternatives are welcome.

Comment: Normally empty lines in the data, where you want the jump, should do the trick, but for some reason it only works for inline data, a la `\addplot table {<actual data>};`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for that. However, I don't want to change the table.

Comment: A concept: You could use something like `x expr=\thisrowno{0}` but hook into `\thisrowno` to place unbound values at desired points. I am thinking of it like `x expr=\discontrow{0}{{3,4},{5,6}}`. Then `discontrow` calls `\thisrow{0}` but places a row with only `nan` between rows 3 & 4 and rows 5 & 6. I just have no idea how to do that, because the definitions behind `\thisrowno` are nearly untraceable in the source.

Comment: Is it OK to transpose the table and insert dummy columns then transpose back? :P

Comment: @percusse if all of that can be done internally (using `\datatable`) and not directly changing the actual data table, then it's OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two options:

1) **If you can modify your table** an easy fix is to add somesort of undefined data and use the option `unbounded coords=jump`. Either "nan" or "inf" will work. I don't post the result because it looks exactly like you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
1   19.178  26.027  8.219   6.849   39.726  1
2   54.795  21.918  4.110   6.849   12.329  1
3   28.767  16.438  6.849   8.219   39.726  1
nan   nan  nan  nan   nan   nan  nan
4   63.014  2.740   2.740   8.219   28.767  2
5   90.411  1.370   6.849   0.000   1.370  2
6   15.068  2.740   16.438  8.219   57.534  2
nan
7   67.123  0.000   0.000   1.000   32.877  3
8   72.603  6.849   5.479   5.000   15.068  3
9   56.164  12.329  6.849   4.110   20.548  3
10  50.685  4.110   8.219   1.370   35.616  3
}\datatable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump]
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=4] \datatable;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

2) **If the table CANNOT be modified** I suggest splitting the plot and definining `domains`. This is not without problems because you will have to repeat the format in these, (like `[red, solid, thick,...])`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[forget plot] table[x index=0,y index=4, restrict x to domain=0:3] \datatable;
\addplot+[forget plot] table[x index=0,y index=4, restrict x to domain=4:6] \datatable;
\addplot+[           ] table[x index=0,y index=4, restrict x to domain=7:10] \datatable;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking (as stated in the question) for an option not involving modifications to the data table.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I leave it because some else can find it useful, did you try with `filters`?

Comment: No problem. If a solution without modifications to the table is not possible, this is a valid alternative :) Yes, I tried with filters but didn't manage to get the desired results; I am not very familiar with their use.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to modify the table you will have to enter the ranges _somehow_. I suggest splitting the plots and defining the `domain`s. See my edit.