# Switch from in-code data table to external file in macro

Tags: pgfplots

I have used the very nice grouping macro described here:

[How can I mix an "ybar" and an "ybar stacked" with pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55554/how-can-i-mix-an-ybar-and-an-ybar-stacked-with-pgfplots)

I would like to be able to use it with data that I have read from a file. How can that be achieved? Instead of the data table written into the tex file, I would like to have it outside, in its own file. How can I do that so that the references to \datatable in the grouping function still work?

Comment: See "4.2.8 Reading coordinates From Files" on page 51 of the pgfplots manual.

Comment: I have read data from files for plots (as described in the manual), and although I have had no trouble plotting in that way, I have not been able to make the grouping function I linked to work when I read data from a file. Perhaps setting a label to the table read from a file would work, but I have not succeeded in doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `mytable.dat` be you data file, then substitute all the `\pgfplotstableread` environment with

```
\pgfplotstableread{mytable.dat}\datatable
```

and that's all.

Comment: I thought I had tried that, but I must have done something wrong earlier, because it did indeed work.