# How to add a Data Table, Error Bar and Grid Line like below diagram?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, tikz-pic

I created a bar graph, but struggle in added in Data Table, Error bar, Grid line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={10pt 20pt 5pt 5pt}]{standalone}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}   % <---

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{
interval  carT  carD
    1    68    32
    2    12.8   3.8
    3    15.5    10.4
    4    14.0    17.3
    5    7.9    21.3
    6   68    32
    7    68   32
    8    68   32
    9    68   32
   10    68   32
        }\mydata

    \begin{axis}[
    width=\linewidth,
    height=.8\linewidth,
    ybar=0.5mm,         % <--- distance between bars (shift bar)
    bar width=4.4mm,    % <--- width of bars
    legend style={legend columns=-1,
      outer sep=1mm,    % <---
      font=\scriptsize, % <---
      anchor=north,
      at={(0.5,1)},
                  },
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize, inner sep=2pt}, % <---
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ylabel={\%},
    xlabel={X-axis},
    ymin=0, ymax=100,     % <---              
    xtick=data,
    scale only axis,     % <---
        ]
    \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
    \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
    \legend{Trips, Distance}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what is the difference to your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/505861/95441)?

Comment: @StefanPinnow, deleted my previous questions

Comment: So far it is unclear how you determine the error bars. Is that a fixed (absolute/relative) value or is it individual for each bar? In the latter case, please add the error values to the data table. Then I guess we are able to help you.

Comment: @StefanPinnow. Because I used Excel, I am able to add `Chat Element`, and then `Error Bar` and then `Percentage`. Each test are total of 100%

Comment: @StefanPinnow, code not reproduce showed image. Image serve only as illustration, where OP like to have table below of diagram (instead of `tick` and `ticklabels`) produced by provided code. However content of table is not known (seems can be any). On that way i understand this question.

Comment: Regarding the last two questions add e.g. `ymajorgrids=true,error bars/y dir=both,error bars/y fixed relative=0.1` to the `axis` options.

Comment: Regarding the first question I guess its a duplicate. Have a look at e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401898/95441 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371573/95441.